# Cannot start Settings$UserSettingsActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an application that displays all activities of all apps. It displayed the MultiUser Settings activity as

`com.android.settings.Settings$UserSettingsActivity`

Clicking on the above shortcut from this app launches the regular multiuser settings activity. But when I try to start the same activity from `am` or other ways like application intent, it fails to start.

I tried from adb,
`am start com.android.settings.Settings$UserSettingsActivity`
and the result log is

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=com.android.settings.Settings }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.settings.Settings }
```

I also tried to start it from application intent like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings.Settings", "com.android.settings.Settings.UserSettingsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Still it doesn't work.

My android device version is 5.1.1 lollipop.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the following command:

```
am start com.android.settings.Settings$UserSettingsActivity
```

adb takes `com.android.settings.Settings$UserSettingsActivity` as a package name and tries to find a launch `Intent` for that package, which fails (because `com.android.settings.Settings$UserSettingsActivity` is not a package name.

If you want to launch a specific component, the syntax is:

```
am start com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$UserSettingsActivity
```

You need to specify the package name and the class name separated by "/"

---

When you do this in code:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings.Settings", "com.android.settings.Settings.UserSettingsActivity"));
```

you are passing the wrong arguments to the `ComponentName` constructor. The constructor takes 2 arguments: package name and class name. This needs to be like this:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$UserSettingsActivity"));
```

The package name is "com.android.settings" and the class name is "com.android.settings.Settings$UserSettingsActivity" which is an inner class of "com.android.settings.Settings".

Comment: I want to point out that - in this specific example - launching the activity mentioned above will be the same as launching the parent type (i.e. dropping the `$UserSettingsActivity`)
As per the [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/platform-tools-29.0.4/AndroidManifest.xml#L2475), launching this specific activity can best be done using a plain `am start -a android.settings.USER_SETTINGS`. This comment doesn't change the answer's relevance or validity